# bluealsa: Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa

Tags: audio, alsa, bluetooth

So as reading the [documentation](https://github.com/Arkq/bluez-alsa#configuration--usage) of `bluealsa`:

> It will register `org.bluealsa` service in the D-Bus system bus, which can be used for accessing configured audio devices.

But when I run

```
$ bluealsa
```

it gives me this exception:

```
bluealsa: Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa
```

So where is the problem and if it's significant one how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Reading the documentation you posted, I found this paragraph at the end of the troubleshooting section:

> 3. Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa
>
> It is not possible to run more than one instance of the BlueALSA server per D-Bus interface. If one tries to run second instance, it will fail with the "Couldn't acquire D-Bus name: org.bluealsa" error message. This message might also appear when D-Bus policy does not allow acquiring "org.bluealsa" name for a particular user - by default only root is allowed to start BlueALSA server.

Since `bluealsa` is designed to start on boot, have you checked if it is already running on your system?

Also, you seem to not be able to start `bluealsa` as any user besides `root`, your question looks to have a non-privileged user prompt when you attempt to execute `bluealsa`.